# How to avoid decimal values for offset().left

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am building a flyout menu using `<ul>`'s.

Example:

```
<ul class="uiMenu">
    <li>One
        <ul>
           <li>Test Child</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Two
         <ul>
           <li>Test Child 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

So the flyout for the menu's `left` `offset` should be the `offset` of the parent menu item's `left` `offset`.

When I iterate thru each parent `<li>` I notice the offset's are decimal values.
But in older versions of IE they are not, just for simplicity I would like to avoid decimal offsets.

Any idea to make sure the offset values end up being integers?

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/gmcalab/V3xNv/)

Answer (score 6):

Just round/floor it with `Math.round()`/`Math.floor()`:

```
Math.round($(this).offset().left);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **parseInt(offsetValue)** method. This rounds a decimal.

Comment: No, this will not solve the problem, because the offset of the element I am basing this off of will still be a decimal value, making flyout menu not aligned with the parent item.

Answer (score 0):

A neat javascript trick is that a shift-left by zero places will truncate any decimal places, in effect doing the same as `Math.floor()`
eg,

```
/* this == 1 */
1.3 << 0;
/* also == 1 */
1.8 << 0;
```

Note however, this isonly of any benefit in the tightest of loops - if you suspect a function table lookup for Math.floor() and stack push/pops are actually costing you time.

Just putting it here for reference. using `Math.round()` or `Math.floor()` is going to be the more correct answer for your problem, due to it being much more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Use

$(document).ready(function(){

```
$('.uiMenu > li').each(function(){

    console.log('offset().left: ' + parseInt($(this).offset().left));
});
```

});

Answer (score -1):

It iterates all the LI elements inside 'uiMenu'. For better and non-conflicting code. Provide IDs to top title lis.

```
<ul class="uiMenu">
    <li class="title">One
        <ul>
           <li>Test Child</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="title">Two
         <ul>
           <li>Test Child 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="title">Three</li>
</ul>
```

Do coding by selecting the `.title`

```
  $('.title ').each(function(){
          console.log('offset().left: ' + $(this).offset().left);
        });
```